# Exclude a specific Python version in conda-build recipe

Tags: python, conda, conda-build

I have a private Python package I build with [conda-build](https://github.com/conda/conda-build) which depends on [pywinauto](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto). This package has some issues with Python 3.7.6 which is documented here: https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/issues/868. The issue seems to be fixed with Python 3.7.7 which will be released sometime in March 2020.

My problem is right now I am unable to build my package because conda-build uses the most recent version of Python 3.7 (which is 3.7.6) during build and import testing. Is there a way to exclude a specific Python version in the conda-build recipe, like the `python_requires` (https://packaging.python.org/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/#python-requires) keyword for `setup.py`?